How do I connect a Pogo pin magnet type, 2P, 10.0D?

How would I connect this magnetic connector?
What are the three pins of the electrical component?
Would it be connected similarly to a USB-C?
The datasheet only provides specific measurements and some Electrical specifications.
Datasheet

Add a photo of the connector. It's not obvious from your description. (I removed the SHOUTING from your question title.)

Connect to what? To a PCB? If so, design a PCB with the pads as specified in the mechanical drawing. Note that the two outer terminals are for the same circuit.
Or you you mean "mate"? If so, this is the mate: Pogo Pin Magnet Type, 2P, 8.0D, DIP, 10u'', 200g, 2A, black

I want to connect it to a PCB. I want to use it to charge a lipo battery. I am not aware of how I should connect it up.

As I said: "design a PCB with the pads as specified in the mechanical drawing."
